# Google play requires 4132500 - with any google-play-service library version imported

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

Trying to work with an emulator using the google maps V2 api I've stumbled upon many solution which resorted to importing some version of the play-service-lib and the associated apk files of the maps and store. [Example](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=527#comment-8168)

Everytime I get the same error : `AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value. Expected 4132500…`
Tried it with several avd types and still come up with nothing.

Any idea how to solve this ? I've also removed the following tag from the manifest.

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

UPDATE:
I've removed the support library also, still the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

add 4132500 instead of "@integer/google_play_services_version"

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="4132500" />
```